# How do I get sed to read from standard input?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying

```
grep searchterm myfile.csv | sed 's/replaceme/withthis/g'
```

and getting

```
unknown option to `s'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

As per the comments the code is actually correct.  My full code resembled something like the following

```
grep searchterm myfile.csv | sed 's/replaceme/withthis/g'
# my comment
```

And it appears that for some reason my comment was being fed as input into sed. Very strange.

Comment: Do you want to replace your file with 'withthis' in the place of replacename?

Comment: No, that's not what you're trying. There's something else missing.

Comment: My best guess is that in your real case you have a `/` in `replaceme` or `withthis`. Try: `'s#replaceme#withthis#g'`.

Comment: One thing that you're doing wrong is not showing us exactly what you are executing.  The code you show is fine; you've got a problem with what you're executing; ergo, you are not showing us what you're executing.  We can't debug what we can't see, most of the time.  Sometimes, we'll get lucky and guess right, but we shouldn't be having to guess or be lucky.

Comment: Useless use of grep.  With sed, you can do:  sed '/searchterm/s/pattern/replacement/g' myfile.csv

Answer (score 168, accepted):

use the --expression option

```
grep searchterm myfile.csv | sed --expression='s/replaceme/withthis/g'
```

Comment: +SOaddict, This is just outputting to stdout, it isn't changing the myfile.csv.

Comment: If you are wanting to do an in-place update of the file, I think my answer adequately solves that issue.

Comment: Anything which looks like `grep 'x' y | sed 'z'` can be refactored to `sed '/x/z' y`. See also [useless use of `grep`.](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep)

Comment: Most devs aren't going to know the shorthand way to do something within a language they likely don't also know how to do the long way

Answer (score 64):

use "-e" to specify the sed-expression

```
cat input.txt | sed -e 's/foo/bar/g'
```

Comment: I was wondering how using "-e" to specify the sed-expression can get sed to read from stdin? Does sed by default read from stdin?

Comment: yes. like most un*x tools, `sed` reads from stdin if no input file is present.

Comment: Thanks. is `-e` necessary? It works without `-e`. I wonder what's the purpose of using `-e`? Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question of OP. `echo foo | sed  's/foo/bar/g'` works without `-e`, by outputing `bar`. So I must have missed his question.

Comment: There is no need to specify `-e` if you only have a single script statement. If you have two, you can say `sed -e '/foo/!d' -e 's//bar/g'` or `sed 's/foo!d;s//bar/g'` (or equivalently, with a newline instead of a semicolon).

Comment: The [`cat` is useless.](/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Comment: @tripleee the question specifically asks about how to use `stdin`; the `cat` is there as a placeholder to generate a stdin, not to demonstrate how to get the input of a file into `sed`. also, thanks for commenting on an 8 year old answer ;-)

Answer (score 7):

To make `sed` catch from stdin , instead of from a file, you should use `-e`.

Like this:

```
curl -k -u admin:admin https://$HOSTNAME:9070/api/tm/3.8/status/$HOSTNAME/statistics/traffic_ips/trafc_ip/ | sed -e 's/["{}]//g' |sed -e 's/[]]//g' |sed -e 's/[\[]//g' |awk  'BEGIN{FS=":"} {print $4}'
```

Comment: -e has nothing to to with input redirection from what I've seen. Instead, your use of -e would eliminate calling sed multiple times. You can pipe the output independent of -e

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to do an in-place update of text within a file, this is much easier to reason about in my mind.

```
grep -Rl text_to_find directory_to_search 2>/dev/null | while read line; do  sed -i 's/text_to_find/replacement_text/g' $line; done
```

Answer (score -21):

1. Open the file using `vi myfile.csv`
2. Press <kbd>Escape</kbd>
3. Type `:%s/replaceme/withthis/`
4. Type `:wq` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Now you will have the new pattern in your file.

Comment: OP wanted to know how to do it with sed, not with vim.

Comment: What Noe said. Also, your vim solution is inferior to the sed alternative(s) as it isn't (easily) scriptable.